# Make public Discord channel activity private for each user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have been searching everywhere and there might be a simple solution but I can't seem to find it.

I have a Discord channel that will be open to everyone in the server. Inside the channel I plan on having a form with drop down or select menus for users to submit.

If I have 100 people in my server and multiple users go to submit the form at the same time, how can I make the channel private for each user, so no one can see what the other is doing?

I was thinking about using modals, how is the UX with them? Do they work well on mobile devices?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the user has to invoke some kind of interaction (ie, slash command or button press) to trigger the form, then just send the form/message ephemerally so only the user who triggered the interaction can see it. Multiple users can do it at the same time and they'll have their own version of the messages to do.

- [Interaction response docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) - just pass `ephemeral` as True in `send_message`
- [discord FAQ](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000580222-Ephemeral-Messages-FAQ) on ephemeral messages

Just don't give any of the UI elements in the form message custom IDs; as that'll cause some issues if multiple people submit them simultaneously.

Alternatively, you can use `modals` as you say, but currently they only support text fields. So if you want free text fields, then use a modal (they work great on desktop, web, and via apps) but if you want to use dropdowns you can just use ephemeral messages. Message UI doesn't currently support text field either - so you can have one or the other but not both! Modals are also inherently private, so only the user that invoked it can see it.